# Tower of Hanoi solving with helper values

Tags: python

This code I've written does solves the hanoi problem when I have all the values in the source array. However, when it is being solved halfway with values in the helper array, it doesn't seem to work.

How can I code it in such a way that it checks if the helper array has value and work from there. The recursive function currently runs once after source is empty

```
# Source, helper, target are arrays. n = height
def solve(n, source, helper, target):
    if n > 0:
        # First we move a tower of size n-1 from the peg source to the helper peg.
        solve(n - 1, source, target, helper)
        if source:
            # Move the largest disk to the target
            target.append(source.pop())
        # Move the tower from helper to target
        solve(n - 1, helper, source, target)

source = [4]
target = []
helper = [3,2,1]
solve(len(source),source,helper,target)
print source, helper, target
```

Comment: If you just want to check if helper array has a value or not, check if the length is 0 or not -- if len(helper) > 0: do something....

Comment: The algorithm you're using solves the entire Tower of Hanoi problem, starting with its standard initial state.  It has absolutely no ability to start in other states, as it's not even looking at what's on the pegs - it just blindly moves them according to a pattern that's only valid from the normal start state.  The only way I can think of to do that would be to run the standard solution as a simulation, and only start emitting actual moves once the simulation matches the given state.  Of course, this will fail miserably if the given state isn't one that occurs during the optimum solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, your current code only works if all the values are in the `source` list. As [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) points out in the comments, it never actually looks at the values in the lists, it just follows a pattern that works for the normal starting configuration.

If you start with a partially solved board, or worse a board that has been randomly rearranged, you'll need to examine the contents of the lists in order to figure out what extra work needs to be done. Here's a solution that I think should work as long as your lists contain integers increasing from `1` (to whatever the maximum is):

```
def solve(n, source, helper, dest):
    assert(n in source)  # precondition

    for x in range(n - 1, 0, -1):  # this loop does nothing if n=1, so we don't need to check
        if x in source:
            solve(x, source, dest, helper)
            break
        elif x in dest:
            solve(x, dest, source, helper)
            break

    # at this point all values smaller than n will be in the helper list
    dest.append(source.pop())

    if n > 1:
        solve(n - 1, helper, source, dest)

    # postcondition: all values from n down to 1 are in dest
```

The `n` value needs to be the largest value you want to move, so using `len(source)` to get it will be wrong if some values are in the other lists. Using `max(source)` might make sense, but it can move any value in the list you want (you don't need to move the full stack).